# plotting large time series efficiently (matplotlib)

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot three time series on the same axes using matplotlib.  Each time series has 10^6 data points.  While I have no problem generating the figure, the PDF output is large and very slow to open in viewers.  Aside from working in a rasterized format, or only plotting a subset of the time series, is there a way to get better graphical performance?  I have tried "optimizing" in acrobat, and I have also had the same trouble with matlab.

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=np.loadtxt('data.txt')
idx = data[:,0]
y1 = data[:,1]
y2 = data[:,2]
y3 = data[:,3]
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', size=16)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


ax.plot(idx,y1,color='b',label=r'$y_1$',
    linewidth=2.0,markersize=10,fillstyle='none')
ax.plot(idx,y2,color='g',label=r'$y_2$',
    linewidth=2.0,markersize=10,fillstyle='none')
ax.plot(idx,y3,color='r',label=r'$y_3$',
    linewidth=2.0,markersize=10,fillstyle='none')

plt.xlabel(r'Index')
plt.ylabel(r'Vales')

legend = ax.legend(loc='upper right',fontsize=16)
ax.set_xscale('log')

plt.savefig('fig1.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Recommend you post your code (or pseudocode) to demonstrate what you're doing, I can see this being closed without it as too broad.

Comment: This is inherent to the PDF/vector-style output format, and matplotlib was created to produce "publication quality figures", thus may have quite detailed vector objects. If you would be able to not plot markers for each point, but just a line connecting the various points, that may save you a lot of postscript strokes in the PDF, and could cut things down to half.