# Figures with lots of data points in matplotlib

Tags: pdf, matplotlib, pdf-generation

I generated the attached image using matplotlib (png format).  I would like to use eps or pdf, but I find that with all the data points, the figure is really slow to render on the screen. Other than just plotting less of the data, is there anyway to optimize it so that it loads faster?

[image]

Comment: If you use a line `-` instead of points (assuming this is `plot` not `scatter` ) the line simplification code might help you out.  If you really want all of your points as, well points, you are kind of stuck as in the vector backends you more-or-less have the commands "move to x, y; draw mark; move to ..." for every point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [plotting large time series efficiently (matplotlib)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668524/plotting-large-time-series-efficiently-matplotlib)

Answer (score 8):

I think you have three options:

1. As you mentioned yourself, you can plot fewer points. For the plot you showed in your question I think it would be fine to only plot every other point.
2. As @tcaswell stated in his comment, you can use a line instead of points which will be rendered more efficiently.
3. You could rasterize the blue dots. Matplotlib allows you to selectively rasterize single artists, so if you pass `rasterized=True` to the plotting command you will get a bitmapped version of the points in the output file. This will be way faster to load at the price of limited zooming due to the resolution of the bitmap. (Note that the axes and all the other elements of the plot will remain as vector graphics and font elements).

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to show a "trend" in your plot , and considering the x,y arrays you are plotting are "huge" you could apply a random sub-sampling to your x,y arrays, as a fraction of your data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fraction = 0.50
x_resampled = []
y_resampled = []

for k in range(0,len(x)):
   if np.random.rand() < fraction:
       x_resampled.append(x[k])
       y_resampled.append(y[k])

plt.scatter(x_resampled,y_resampled , s=6)
plt.show()
```

Second, have you considered using log-scale in the x-axis to increase visibility?

Comment: That loop seems *very* slow. Try `x_subsampled = x[np.random.rand(*x.shape) < fraction]`.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, only the plotting area is rasterized, the axis are still in vector format:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.uniform(size=400000)
y = np.random.uniform(size=400000)
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='x', rasterized=False)
plt.savefig("norm.pdf", format='pdf')
```

[image]